# Definition of Continuous Function Question

Tags: real-analysis

"Elementary Analysis" by Ross states that if f is a real valued function, with domain as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, f is continuous at $x_0 \epsilon$ dom(f) if for every sequence ($x_n$) $\epsilon$ dom(f) converging to $x_0$, we have lim f($x_n$) = f($x_0$).

I'm having trouble understanding this, and I'm trying to think of an example.

If f = $x^2$ with dom(f) = $\mathbb{R}$ and we look at the point $x_0$ = 2. Then, for example, the sequence $x_n$ = 2 + $\frac{1}{x_n + 1}$ converges to 2. So lim f(2 + $\frac{1}{x_n + 1}$) = lim ( 2 + $\frac{1}{x_n + 1}$)$^2$ = 4 = f(2).

So for this sequence it's true, (sorry if this is a dumb question) but how can you be sure every sequence converging to $x_0$ has the same result?

Comment: There are many equivalent def'ns of continuity Which one are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a result in topology. The statement
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x_0)
$$
Is equivalent to $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\mid n \geq n_0 \implies |f(x_n) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

Since $x_n \to x_0$, we have $\forall \delta > 0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\mid n \geq n_0 \implies |x_n - x_0| < \delta$, and conversely $\forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \exists \delta > 0\mid n \geq n_0 \implies |x_n - x_0|<\delta$.

so $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x_0)$ is equivalent to **for every** $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converging to $x_0$, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0\mid |x_n - x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x_n) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$, which is the precise definition of continuity.

Notice that we did not place any assumption on $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ except for its convergence to $x_0$, so it does hold for every sequence.

Comment: I appear to have down voted this. If you edit it, I'll change it to an upvote

Comment: @Stella Biderman Thanks. I've edited.